# Picklist value not appearing on Record created after the picklist value

Tags: picklist, record-type

I have a picklist field on the `Contact object`, called `GS - areas of interest`. A number of `Contact records` were created before this picklist field. After creating the picklist field, I updated it by adding some further options, in this case, the option is called `Theology`.

On `Contact records` which were created **before** this new picklist value was added to the `Contact object`, the value **is available** to select, as shown below:
[image]

On `Contact records` which were created **after** this new picklist value was added to the `Contact object`, the value **is not available** to select, as shown below:
[image]

I've double-checked the `Record types` on the `Contact object`, but these show that the `Theology` picklist value is available for the `Contact record type` I am using, as shown below:
[image]

It feels like a logical issue, as the problem occurs for `Contact records` created **after** the picklist value was created, but I cannot for the life of me work out where I am going wrong.

With many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that Gs areas of interest is dependant on any field? If yes, please check field dependencies also for the piclist value availablity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MohanRaj. Unfortunately, there are no dependencies for this Picklist field.

Comment: The only way I've managed to resolve this, for the time being, is by duplicating the field and migrating data over to it. 

Not really an ideal resolution, but solves the problem for the time being.